# Functional dependencies, type families, and type synonyms

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

A simple toy class with functional dependencies,

```
class C a b | a -> b, b -> a where
    f :: a -> a
    g :: b -> b
```

is to be instantiated once with type synonym `I`

```
type I = Int

instance C I Double where
    f = id
    g = id
```

and once with type synonym `J`

```
type J = Int

instance C J Float where
    f = id
    g = id
```

GHC does not like this, it sees a functional dependencies conflict. `I` and `J` are considered identical, i.e. `Int`. I can sort of see why it would. On the other hand, if GHC had accepted this, I wouldn't have complained.

Not surprisingly, the same happens with type families.

Am I right in concluding that the only way out is to introduce wrappers like

```
newtype I = I Int
newtype J = J Int
```

or is there a way to avoid the wrapping-unwrapping?

Comment: Yes, like you noticed, `I` and `J` are both identical to `Int` and the type system cannot, _should not_ be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Well you do not per se need to make *two* `newtypes`. You can write `type I = Int`, `newtype J = J Int`. But you will somehow need to construct a type yes. That being said, why do you use functional dependencies in the first place if you want both `C Int Double` and `C Int Float` to exist?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Without the functional dependencies I get ambiguous type variables.

Comment: Maybe you should have only `b -> a` but not `a -> b`?

Comment: @mcmayer: well at first sight, it looks like `f` and `g` do not have much "in common". So it might perhaps make more sense to define two classes `C1 a` and `C2 b`, and define `f` in `C1` and `g` in `C2`. But that might of course depend on the situation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need both `a->b` and `b->a` or I get ambiguous type variables. (Just on the basis of a symmetry argument.) Splitting up the class is certainly a path forward, but in my real-world case the classes and dependencies begin to resemble a jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I need both `a->b` and `b->a` or I get ambiguous type variables. (Just on the basis of a symmetry argument.)

Comment: @mcmayer You might need to provide less of a toy class; you may have an XY problem.